# Material Table - validates onAdd before any input

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui

Basically when I click onAdd (the plus), an row is added and it tells me my input (email) is wrong.

[image]

I want it to say nothing initially and the submit still be disabled. Is there any way?

```
<MaterialTable

editable={{
            onRowAdd: onCreateProfile,
          }}

columns={[
            {
              title: 'Email',
              field: 'Email',
              validate: (rowData) => {
                if (rowData.Email === undefined || rowData.Email === '') {
                  return 'Empty'
                } else if (!rowData.Email.includes('@' && '.') || rowData.Email.length < 3) {
                  return 'Email is not valid'
                }
                return true
              },
            },
          ]}
/>
```

the onCreateProfile function only gets called after submitting.

Comment: Please provide more of the code contents.